# Vue-resource post method - send form to php file

Tags: javascript, post, vue.js, vue-resource

I am using vue-resource post method and I would like to send email form to my php file.

```
request() {
  const formData = {
      name: this.name,
      email: this.email,
      textarea: this.textarea
  };
  this.$http.post('index.php', formData, {emulateJSON: true})
  .then((response) => {
    $router.push(thankyou);
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
  });
}
```

After submitting the form I get the response `status 404`, and `POST http://localhost:8080/index.php 404 (Not Found)` 
I've got the php file in main folder of my project.

Comment: What is Vue.http.options.root set to? How does your vue-resource config file look like?

Comment: Saw your comments and deleted my answer. Can you trace the network activity in the DevTools window and check what the details of the HTTP requests are? Request URL, etc ...

Comment: Yeah, so: `Request URL:http://localhost:8080/index.php`, `Request Method:POST`, `Status Code:404 Not Found`